# Can I replace Host Names on Fiddler results?

Tags: fiddler

Fiddler's host field is not always clear, especially with IP direct calls, or service calls I don't recognize.

I would like a way to replace certain names or name regex, with other more clearly defined names.

for instance, "193-149-72-221.drip.trouter.io" actually means Skype traffic, though the IP changes.  so I would prefer to use: "*.drip.trouter.io".

Or, if there is a tag field or something like that that I can apply to hosts, and show the column in the list.  I'm pretty flexible, but I'd really like to be able to classify or rename hosts to something I can recognize easier at a glance.

(I have looked around for this on google and checked similar questions on here with no luck)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click Rules > Customize Rules.

```
public static BindUIColumn("MyFunkyName", 60)
function FillNameColumn(oS: Session): String {    
    if (oS.hostname.EndsWith("trouter.io") return "SkypeStuff";
    if (oS.hostname.EndsWith("bunnies.com") return "CuteStuff";
    return oS.hostname;
}
```

Save the file. You now have a column titled `MyFunkyName` which shows a string based on the hostname of the target.